# Stop auto rotate on bxslider when window resized to 776px and smaller

Tags: javascript, slider, bxslider

How would I make the bxslider to not auto rotate when the window size is 767px or smaller? Here is my code

```
 var slider = $('.bxslider-wrapper').bxSlider({
        autoHover: true,
        tickerHover: true,
        controls: false,
        pause: options.auto != '' ? options.auto : 4000,
        pager: options.showControls ? options.showControls : false,
        auto: options.auto != '' ? true : false,
        infiniteLoop: options.continuous ? options.continuous : false,
        touchEnabled: isTouchableDevice()
    });
```

Comment: Get the width of the viewport prior to initializing your slider and wrap your initialization with a conditional. `if(window_width > 776) {//your options} else {//other options}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var width = $(window).width(); // get width of viewport
  if(width > 776) {
    var slider = $('.bxslider-wrapper').bxSlider({
        autoHover: true,
        tickerHover: true,
        controls: false,
        pause: options.auto != '' ? options.auto : 4000,
        pager: options.showControls ? options.showControls : false,
        auto: false
        infiniteLoop: options.continuous ? options.continuous : false,
        touchEnabled: isTouchableDevice()
    });
  } else {
    var slider = $('.bxslider-wrapper').bxSlider({
        autoHover: true,
        tickerHover: true,
        controls: false,
        pause: options.auto != '' ? options.auto : 4000,
        pager: options.showControls ? options.showControls : false,
        auto: true
        infiniteLoop: options.continuous ? options.continuous : false,
        touchEnabled: isTouchableDevice()
    });
  }
});
```

You may want to add an event to update the width variable on screen resize.